# Copy table from one database to another database

Tags: mysql

I am trying to copy a table from one database to another database.

Already there are several solutions for this problem. I use this method to solve this problem.

```
 select  *
into    DbName.dbo.NewTable
from    LinkedServer.DbName.dbo.OldTableSourceDB..MySourceTable
```

I have two databases. One is `blog` including a table named `engineers`; another database named `msdata` including a table named `ms`. I am trying to copy the table `engineers` to the database `msdata`. My query is:

```
select * into msdata.dbo.ms from linkedserver.blog.dbo.engineers;
```

but output is

```
Undeclared variable: msdata
```

I don't know it is the problem here. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: mySQL or SQL server? dbo implies SQL server along with Linked Server vs [Federated Engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html)

Comment: Yes it is mysql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an illustration:

```
create table so_gibberish.fred1
(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    what varchar(40) not null
);

insert so_gibberish.fred1 (what) values ('this'),('that');


insert into newdb789.fred1 select * from so_gibberish.fred1;

-- failed, error code 1146: Table 'newdb789.fred1' doesn't exist

create table newdb789.fred1
(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    what varchar(40) not null
);

insert into newdb789.fred1(id,what) select id,what from so_gibberish.fred1;
insert into newdb789.fred1 (what) values ('a new thing');

select * from newdb789.fred1;

+----+-------------+
| id | what        |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | this        |
|  2 | that        |
|  3 | a new thing |
+----+-------------+
```

**good**, auto_increment preserved and resumes at 3 for new things

Comment: Thank you very much drew for your clear explanation. Actually you are a good programmer. May god bless you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this alternative query below, make sure you have already created the table in destination database:

```
INSERT INTO DestinationDatabase..DestinationTable 
SELECT * FROM SourceDatabase..SourceTable;
```